# Turning String into Integer inside tkinter Entry

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently experimenting with tkinter in python, but I couldnt figure out how to turn the string that is written inside an Entry to an integer.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
erstertext = Label(window, text="Hi! You have to enter your information for this program.")
erstertext.pack()

agetext = Label(window, text="Age:")
agetext.pack()
ageinput = Entry(window,)
ageinput.pack()
nametext = Label(window, text="First Name:")
nametext.pack()
nameinput = Entry(window,)
nameinput.pack()

x = ageinput.get()


def callback():
     if x >= 18:
         Text1 = Label(window, text="Hi " + nameinput.get() + " , you are " + ageinput.get() + "or older")
         Text1.pack()

     else:
        Text2 = Label(window, text="Hi " + nameinput.get() + " ur younger than 18")
        Text2.pack()

button1 = Button(window, text="Done",command=callback)
button1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

The relevant part:

```
from tkinter import * 

agetext = Label(window, text="Age:")
agetext.pack()
ageinput = Entry(window,)
ageinput.pack()

x = ageinput.get()


def callback():
     if x >= 18:
         Text1 = Label(window, text="Hi " + nameinput.get() + " , you are " + ageinput.get() + "or older")
         Text1.pack()
```

I currently use Python 3.9

I tried turning x into an integer in the callback section

```
def callback():
     if int(x) >= 18:
         Text1 = Label(window, text="Hi " + nameinput.get() + " , you are " + ageinput.get() + "or older")
         Text1.pack()
```

still didnt work. Then I tried putting the ageinput.get directly into a int

```
def callback():
     if int(ageinput.get) >= 18:
         Text1 = Label(window, text="Hi " + nameinput.get() + " , you are " + ageinput.get() + "or older")
         Text1.pack()
```

and it doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your program gets the age input before the window is even shown on the screen.

The variable `x`, is only retrieved once and remains static for the duration of the program.

Move the line where you get the age input inside of the callback... for example:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
erstertext = Label(window, text="Hi! You have to enter your information for this program.")
erstertext.pack()

agetext = Label(window, text="Age:")
agetext.pack()
ageinput = Entry(window,)
ageinput.pack()
nametext = Label(window, text="First Name:")
nametext.pack()
nameinput = Entry(window,)
nameinput.pack()

def callback():
     x = ageinput.get()  # this grabs the input text at the time the button is pressed
     if x.isdigit() and int(x) >= 18:
         Text1 = Label(window, text="Hi " + nameinput.get() + " , you are " + ageinput.get() + "or older")
         Text1.pack()

     else:
        Text2 = Label(window, text="Hi " + nameinput.get() + " ur younger than 18")
        Text2.pack()

button1 = Button(window, text="Done",command=callback)
button1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If the input of age is not a number, i.e. `x.isdigit()` returns `False`, the else block will be executed which is not a correct logic.

Comment: @acw1668  you are correct... and I assume the OP will also be able to figure that out for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help. In line 16 I replaced this: `x = ageinput.get()`  to `y = 18`

Here is code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
erstertext = Label(window, text="Hi! You have to enter your information for this program.")
erstertext.pack()

agetext = Label(window, text="Age:")
agetext.pack()
ageinput = Entry(window,)
ageinput.pack()
nametext = Label(window, text="First Name:")
nametext.pack()
nameinput = Entry(window,)
nameinput.pack()

y = 18

def callback():
     if int(ageinput.get()) >= y:
         Text1 = Label(window, text="Hi " + nameinput.get() + " , you are " + ageinput.get() + "or older")
         Text1.pack()

     else:
        Text2 = Label(window, text="Hi " + nameinput.get() + " ur younger than 18")
        Text2.pack()

button1 = Button(window, text="Done",command=callback)
button1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Result before:

[image]

Result after:

[image]

Result less age:

[image]